# Admin-approved User.Read.All scope is not granted in the OAuth token scopes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api, azure-oauth, microsoft-oauth

My Azure app has the scope `User.Read.All` approved by an admin:

[image: admin]

I request the following scopes in my oauth registration:

```yaml
scope:
  - profile
  - email
  - openid
  - offline_access
  - User.Read.All
  - Files.Read.All
```

And manage to successfully make the `authorize` call, getting the following response:

```json
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "profile email openid https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "...",
    "refresh_token": "...",
    "id_token": "..."
}
```

Why is `User.Read.All` not present in the scope of the generated token?

I also verified the token indeed doesn't grant me access to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken",
        "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileAccessDeniedException' was thrown.",
        "innerError": { ... }
    }
}
```

Am I missing some configuration?

If I also request the `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` permission in the scope, I do get a valid response from the `/users` endpoint, however it only contains my own user.

Comment: Could you share the whole request for oauth registration?

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` in the scope requires to add `Application type permission --> User.Read.All` but in your screenshot, you only gave delegated graph api permission.

Comment: @user2250152 I'm using Spring Security to request registration. Its just the scope I mentioned plus clientId, clientSecret

Comment: @TinyWang the permission is in graph api, its just short for `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All`, like Files

Comment: Are you asking for the `User.Read.All` in your authorization request? Not in your app registration, but in your login (token) request? I mean, if you don't ask for it, then you won't be given it (unless you ask for the '.default')

Comment: @Nikolay I do ask for it, I do ask also for `Files.Read.All` and get them, although no mention of this permission in app registration.

Comment: @Mugen, can you please share the client request id and timestamp of the query

Answer (score 0):

The problems with my setup were:

- Should use `/organizations/` tenant instead of `/common/`
- Should use `Delegated` permissions instead of `Application`
- Specify the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` instead of specific graph scopes